# Why Log4j addivity doesn't work?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have the following log4j configuration

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, myappender1    

log4j.appender.myappender1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myappender1.File=D:/phase10/myLog1.log
log4j.appender.myappender1.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.myappender1.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.myappender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myappender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.appender.myappender2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myappender2.File=D:/phase10/myLog2.log
log4j.appender.myappender2.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.myappender2.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.myappender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myappender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.logger.com.my.package=INFO, myappender2 
log4j.addivity.com.my.package=false
```

After this I run app and see in both logs
`INFO` `WARN` `ERROR` messages.

Does my configuration wrong ?

expected result - in `myLog1.log` only `ERROR` messages
in  `myLog2.log` `INFO` `WARN` `ERROR` messages.

If to replace `log4j.addivity.com.my.package=false` with `log4j.addivity=false` I see same result)

### update

thanks @Kevin Tanzer 
after replacing 'addivity' with 'additivity' In myLog1 I see no messages. in myLog2 I see all messages
All mesages logged from `com.my.package`

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-additivity-property-example/

Answer (score 0):

The last configuration item should be 'additivity' not 'addivity', which may be causing your problems.  You've defined two separate appenders.

The myappender1 will have only ERROR (and FATAL) messages.

The myappender2 will get INFO, WARN and ERROR (and FATAL) messages because INFO is a lower severity than the others.  That is, the order is:

TRACE,
DEBUG,
INFO,
WARN,
ERROR and
FATAL